# Using a loop to call up arrays with different names

Tags: c++, arrays, string, loops

I have 5 arrays which I am trying to populate using a loop. I want to ask user for 4 entries for the first array (which I do have a loop for), and then loop to the second, third, fourth, and fifth array.

I need these arrays to be separate, one dimensional arrays.

I can get the info for the first array, but since they all have different names, I cannot figure out how to get the loop to progress to the other arrays.

Here's what I have which gets the info for the first array only...I could just repeat everything 5 times using the different array names, but it seems like there should be a way to use a loop.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <iomanip>
 #include <string>

 using namespace std;


 int main()
 {
 int Array1[4];
 int Array2[4];
 int Array3[4];
 int Array4[4];
 int Array5[4];
 int countArray = 1;

 cout <<" \nEnter 4 integers: \n\n";

 for (countArray; countArray <=4; countArray ++)
     cin >> Array1[countArray];


 // Need to get info in to Array1, followed by Array2, Array3, Array4, Array 5
 // Want ot use a loop to call the other arrays

 countArray = 1;
 cout << "\n\n";
 for (countArray = 1; countArray <=4; countArray ++)
     cout << Array1[countArray] << "  ";;
     cout << "\n\n";

 // Need to outpit info from Array1, followed by Array2, Array3, Array4, Array 5
 // Want ot use a loop to call the other arrays


system("PAUSE");

return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Aside from the answers to your question, you may want to rethink the indexing into your arrays. Your `countArray` for-loop is running from 1..4, whilst `Array1` is declared as `[4]`, meaning it is indexible from **0..3**. Accessing `Array1[n]` where `n` is not in `[0..3]` is therefore undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You should define a function to loop through the input for a single array, and call that function for each of your four arrays:

```
void handleInput(int array[], int count) {
    // Input the data into the array, up to the count index
}
void handleOutput(int array[], int count) {
    // Output the data from the array, up to the count index
}
```

Now you can call these methods from the `main()` passing `Array1`, `Array2`, etc., like this:

```
handleInput(Array1, 3);
handleInput(Array2, 4);
handleInput(Array3, 4);
handleOutput(Array1, 3);
handleOutput(Array2, 4);
handleOutput(Array3, 4);
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense but now I get: 'redefinition of void handleInput (int*, int).

Comment: @user2038219 The `handleInput` and `handleOutput` need to either have a prototype, or you need to move their definitions before `main`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not add the following lines after cin >> Array1[countArray];

```
Array2[countArray] = Array1[countArray];
Array3[countArray] = Array1[countArray];
Array4[countArray] = Array1[countArray];
Array5[countArray] = Array1[countArray];
```

That sould fill them all with the same values at the same indexes.

Comment: Thanks, but I need them to be different values

Answer (score 0):

If sizes of all arrays are equal I suggest you to use 2-dimensional array for this case.

```
int main()
{
    int Array[5][4];
    int countArray = 0;
    int countItem = 0;

    for (countArray = 0; countArray < 5; ++countArray) 
    {
        cout <<" \nEnter 4 integers: \n\n";
        for (countItem = 0; countItem < 4; ++countItem)
            cin >> Array[countArray][countItem];
    }

    // Need to get info in to Array1, followed by Array2, Array3, Array4, Array 5
    // Want ot use a loop to call the other arrays

    cout << "\n\n";
    for (countArray = 0; countArray < 5; ++countArray)
    {
        for (countItem = 0; countItem < 4; ++countItem)
            cout << Array[countArray][countItem] << "  ";
        cout << "\n\n";
    }

    // Need to outpit info from Array1, followed by Array2, Array3, Array4, Array 5
    // Want ot use a loop to call the other arrays

    return 0;
}
```